# dynamic marker color highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am new to highcharts  so any help will be highly appreciated.

See my fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/warnisw/mk9cswjr/525/) 
Is it possible to change marker color based on yaxis values. I try to use zones but it also fills area underneath and line itself which i don't want to.

In this case i want all markers that are under 99.9 turn red. Is it possible using plotOptions and somehow get yaxis values. Can someone point me to proper syntax or other ways to achieve this as i get Uncaught ReferenceError: chart is not defined.

```
      plotOptions: {
    series: {

      marker: {
        //fillColor: chart.get('y-axis') <=99.9 ? "yellow" : "blue"


      }
    }
  },
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the `marker` options for each point:

```
    data.forEach(function(el, i) {
        data[i] = {
            x: el[0],
            y: el[1],
            marker: {
                fillColor: el[1] <= 99.9 ? "yellow" : "blue"
            }
        }
    });
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yjpgqcvw/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data.marker

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what i was looking for.